# Need of specifying the input shape in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, batch-processing, shapes, keras-layer

I am seeking help from put the right form of input_shape,

Let's say if I have the code like:

```
   G  = ImageGenerator(batch_size,args,****kwargs)
```

where G is a custom-made data_generator which specify the batch size  and then fit the data generated from G into :

```
m.fit_generator(G ,#some other parameters)
```

I know at the fist layer of model ,it's necessary to give `input_shape`.

My question is :

In this situation, where batch size have been declared in generator`G`,

Do I have to tell Keras(pass the arguments) when build the first layer :

```
batch_size=32,input_shape=(256,256)
```

or just

```
input_shape=(256,256)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: batch size is not an argument of any layer, only input_shape is necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  Matias Valdenegro :batch size is not an argument of any layer, only input_shape is necessary.